# using moment.js package in ionic 2 project

Tags: angular, ionic2

i want to use in Moment.js package for dates in my project ionic 2 and i'm not sure how to do that
this is the link 
[moment js link](http://momentjs.com/)

i have datetime variable and i want that to be from my zone area.
should i do that? because it's in javascript and ionic 2 use in typescript

i tried to do it but it's not works

```
     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private platform:Platform) {

   mydate=new Date();
   mydate=moment.moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');

  }
```

when i try to use this

```
let data = moment().format('YYYYMMDD');
let time = moment().format('HHmmss');
console.log('today is: ', data + ' and time: ', time);
```

i get this errror
[image]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Check this [link](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/) for typescript.

1 - **Install** via NPM:

```
npm install moment -S
```

2 - **Import** in your Typescript file:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

3 - **Use** in your Typescript file:

```
let data = moment().format('YYYYMMDD');
let time = moment().format('HHmmss');
console.log('today is: ', data + ' and time: ', time);
```

I hope to have been a help to you. :)

**EDIT**: Still works fine with Ionic v3.9.2 (2018-03-08)

Comment: i tried and i get error. i put the photo of the error on my post, i edit it. check

Comment: Uhm, try using an ambient typings install as suggested in places such as http://mhartington.io/post/ionic2-external-libraries/

Comment: Thx @Sampath ^_^

Comment: sir its working but i have to convert below format like : 05 Apr 2019 how to do this?

Comment: @Kapilsoni maybe here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 11):

Thanks @mosca90 you got me 90% of the way!

I used your info to create a custom pipe, which solved my issues completely. Here's the source of the pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import moment from 'moment';

/**
 * Generated class for the MomentjsPipe pipe.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html for more info on
 * Angular Pipes.
 */
@Pipe({
  name: 'momentjs',
})
export class MomentjsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  /**
   * Takes a date value and returns a pretty string from current time, 
   * for instance: "four hours ago" or "in eleven minutes".
   */
  transform(value: string, ...args) {
    return moment(value).fromNow();
    //return value.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

So now I can just do:

```
<div>{{ date | momentjs }}</div>
```

and I see:

```
ten minutes ago.
```

Perfection! Thank you again!

Comment: Cool solution for this.  Thanks for posting

Comment: Hello, Can i convert the time zone from GMT to IST in moment in ionic 3.x