# bundle update failed: 'MomentModule' is not exported by node_modules\angular2-moment\index.js

Tags: angular, ionic2, momentjs, angular-moment, angular2-moment

I am using `ionic2` + `Angular2` and have installed `"angular2-moment": "^1.0.0-beta.6"`. After I have imported I'm getting the following error

Error:

> bundle update failed: 'MomentModule' is not exported by
>   node_modules\angular2-moment\index.js
>
> (imported by src\app\app.module.ts). For help fixing this error see
>   https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#name-is-not-exported-by-module

Code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MomentModule } from "angular2-moment";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginPage,
    TabsPage,
    ReversePipe
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      BrowserModule,

      MomentModule,

      CommonModule,
      HttpModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    LoginPage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [ myApi ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

any help on how to install `MomentModule` with `ionic2`?

Comment: You mean how to use **moment.js** with ionic2?

Comment: Yes, how to use? and why I am getting the above mentioned error?

Comment: Try this: [using moment.js package in ionic 2 project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893257/using-moment-js-package-in-ionic-2-project/39893826#39893826)