# How to install moment.js package and use it in an Ionic app?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, momentjs

How to install [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com) package to an application that built with Ionic framework. And how to use it in the app, in both the `.ts` files and the `.html` files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using moment.js package in ionic 2 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893257/using-moment-js-package-in-ionic-2-project)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a simple guide about how to install `moment.js` package and use it in an Ionic app, in both the typescript files and the view (html) files.

**Install `moment.js` package**

```
npm install moment --save-prod
```

**Install `moment-timezone` package**

```
npm install moment-timezone --save-prod
```

**Import the package in the top of your TypeScript file**

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';
```

Note that we import the `moment-timezone` package, not the `moment` package because this way we can use the methods of the `moment-timezone` package as well as the methods of the `moment` package because the `moment-timezone` package exports them.

**Add it to the declared attributes or variables inside the class in your TypeScript file**

```
export class ClassName {
    // "momentjs" is a name of my choice, you can name it as you like
    momentjs: any = moment;
    //..
    //..
}
```

**Use `moment.js` package in your TypeScript file like this** (for example)

```
// Set the default timezone to UTC
// More info about moment timezone: http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs
this.momentjs.tz.setDefault('UTC');

// Current datetime according to the default timezone (UTC as determined above)
let currentDateTime = this.momentjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ');
console.log(currentDateTime);

// A specific datetime according to a specific timezone ('Africa/Cairo' in this example) other than the default one (UTC as determined above)
let dateTimeAccordingToAnotherTimezone = this.momentjs('2018-10-15 15:59:59').tz('Africa/Cairo').format('DD-MM-YYYY @ hh:mm a ZZ');
console.log(dateTimeAccordingToAnotherTimezone);
```

**Use `moment.js` package in your Ionic view file (html file) like this** (for example)

```
<p>Order Placed at: {{ momentjs(order.created_at).tz('Africa/Cairo').format('DD-MM-YYYY @ hh:mm a') }}</p>
```

This will display the date and time according to the specified timezone and in the specified format.

Comment: How can i pass this ClassName to my application?
If i di it as mixin then a copy of moment will be created for every vue component.
Kindly suggest.